# Strange behaviour of eval() with lambda functions inside a loop in python

Tags: python, function, lambda, constraints, eval

I have a string input file as below (one equation per line):
1.0 - x[0] - x[1]
x[0] + x[1]

I am trying to convert these equations to lambda functions using eval() in python and then use them in an optimization scheme. Here is what I do:

```
def gen_const(input):
    list = input.read_eqs()
    for i in list:
        m = lambda x: eval(i)
        cons.extend([{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': m}])
    return cons
```

This cons fails when it is used inside the optimization scheme. However, if I only consider the first round inside the loop (i.e. first equation), the constraint works fine:

```
def gen_const(input):
    list = input.read_eqs
    for i in list[0:1]:
        m = lambda x: eval(i)
        cons.extend([{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': m}])
    return cons
```

Strangely enough, when I copy the exact same equations (literally copy from the input file, identical characters, spacing) it works fine too:

```
def gen_const(input):
    list = input.read_eqs
    m0 = '1.0 - x[0] - x[1]'
    m1 = 'x[0] + x[1]'
    cons.extend([{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: eval(m0)}])
    cons.extend([{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: eval(m1)}])
return cons
```

So I see this strange behaviour of eval() inside a loop and I really got stuck. I have read that eval is evil and searched through the alternatives but couldn't find a better way that works for my problem.
I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: When you say the constraint fails, do you mean as an exception, or just a failed constraint when you expected it not to fail?

Comment: Hi Phil and thanks for your comment. Just a failed constraint that results in optimization failure when I do not expect it to fail. The third version is identical but it works fine.

Comment: `lambda x: eval(i)` will evaluate `i` *as it exists at the moment the lambda is called* - which will be the final equation in the list if you're looping over more than one equation.  In other words, your constraint is being applied multiple times to the last equation, and not at all to any others.  `lambda x, i=i: eval(i)` would *capture* the value of `i` at the moment the lambda was defined.

Comment: Wow! This worked perfectly! Thanks a lot Jason. Just to clarify, why does lambda x: eval(i) ignores the call of lambda with the iterator? I mean does the compiler overwrite iterator with the last element in the entire loop?

Comment: By the time you get around to calling the lambdas, the iterator variable is holding the final value it was assigned in the loop.  There wouldn't be any problem if you were calling the lambdas during the same iteration in which they were created.