# Why does `eval` not work within a Python class function?

Tags: python, pandas, namespaces, eval, nameerror

Say I have a python class with a Pandas dataframe `df` as attribute. I want to query `df` by releasing one or more pre-defined queries, using a class function to which one or more query handles are provided as arguments:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class doorn:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'foo'
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A':np.arange(0, 10), 'B':np.arange(5, 15), 'C':np.arange(14, 24)}, index=[x for x in range(0, 10)])

    def query_df(self, *query):
        # query arguments must by formatted as 'q1', 'q2' etc
        queries = [q for q in query]

        q1 = self.df.loc[self.df.A > 2].index
        q2 = self.df.loc[self.df.B < 13].index
        q3 = self.df.loc[self.df.C > 15].index

        sel_rows = set().union(*[eval(x, globals(), locals()) for x in queries])

        self.df = self.df.loc[sel_rows]
```

Now, it seems that `eval` cannot find the instances of the query-strings it is provided:

```
>>> foo = doorn()
>>> foo.query_df('q1', 'q2')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 17, in query_df
  File "<input>", line 17, in <listcomp>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'q1' is not defined
```

My guess is that `q1`, `q2`, `q3` are not present in the row comprehension Namespace. Or something, because I haven't really wrapped my head around Namespaces yet. I've tried solving this by providing `globals()` and `locals()` as additional arguments to `eval`, as suggested in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#eval), but without success.

How can I solve this? Can I even refrain from using `eval` altogether?

Comment: Using `eval(queries[0])` works. Also, replacing the for comprehension with a for-loop and appending to a list works as well. This could be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50624105/strange-behaviour-of-eval-with-lambda-functions-inside-a-loop-in-python

Comment: Yes, it works with a `for` loop, thanks for suggesting.

Comment: No problems. I'm not entirely sure why it works though, so it would be nice if someone adds a good answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because the `locals()` in your comprehension loop are not the same as the ones in your function, thus they don't contain 'q1'. You may use global variables but I would not recommend this. 
Moreover using eval with something coming maybe from user inputs can be hazardous has it can execute malicious code.

I suggest you to store your list of predefined queries in a dictionary like in this example:

```
class doorn:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'foo'
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A':np.arange(0, 10), 'B':np.arange(5, 15), 'C':np.arange(14, 24)}, index=[x for x in range(0, 10)])

    def query_df(self, *query):
        # query arguments must by formatted as 'q1', 'q2' etc
        queries = [q for q in query]

        possible_queries = {'q1' : self.df.loc[self.df.A > 2].index,
        'q2' : self.df.loc[self.df.B < 13].index,
        'q3' : self.df.loc[self.df.C > 15].index}

        sel_rows = set().union(*[possible_queries[x] for x in queries])

        self.df = self.df.loc[sel_rows]
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Using a dictionary is a definite improvement while avoiding the `eval` issue.